# How to get value in Fragment from an Activity using setResult?

Tags: android, fragment, onactivityresult, startactivityforresult

Clicking on profile image in a fragment, goes to profile Activity. Now on backPress finishing the acitivity and goes back to fragment.  Now in fragment how can i get value from setResult which i am passing while closing activity as shown in the below code:

Activity Code:

```
 private void closeActivity(boolean isFollowClicked) {
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
    resultIntent.putExtra(Constants.BUNDLE_GRP, isFollowClicked);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
    finish();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    closeActivity(isFollowClick);
}
```

How to get setResult value in Fragment?

Comment: Did you start the activity usin `Fragment.startActivityForResult`?

Comment: No, i used intent

Comment: And which entity used that intent to start that activity?

Comment: using startActivity(intent)

Answer (score 0):

Instead calling `startActivity(intent)` you need to call `startActivityForResult(intent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE)` and from the same fragment class override `onActivityResult(...)` .

After pressing "Back" in the target activity, `onActivityResult(...)` will be called with the result - verify the request code then process the result.